# How to "Bulk Clone" Test Cases on Azure Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, testcase

I need to bulk clone 100+ Test Cases from an Area Path to another because I'll need to edit some details later on on the cloned one.

Problem is that when I move i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while Drag & Dropping but the clone isn't happening, even tried with ADD but the result is the same.

Anyone have a solution?

[image]
Thanks in advance!